# Linux SSH: Can't find a file (though it exists)

Tags: linux, ssh, chmod

I'm experiencing a weird problem, I have a header file that is included in source files (c++),now whenever I run 'make' on any source file I get the error:

```
pin.H: No such file or directory
```

pin.H is found in a different directory (but in some parent directory of the source files), anyway this shouldn't make a problem in my case, the files (sources, headers, makefile, libraries and even exe. files) are given to us by course staff and it's meant to work this way.

I was able to compile successfully before, but somehow after several attempts to run a test on some source file, I had probably made something wrong, I used 'chmod' on some files (and directories maybe), because while trying to run a test I was getting : "Permission denied", However I doubt that I've made chmod for something that it now can't reach that header file anymore (while compiling).

And if that is the case, can I somehow restore "the initial mode" of the system?

Comment: Linux is case sensitive. Are you sure the file is `pin.H` and not `pin.h`?

Comment: @thatotherguy That's not the problem for sure, it really worked well before, also, I thought about that and tried to change the ".H" in a source file to ".h", it didn't help.